# Como posso incrementar um dia para uma data em Java?

Tags: java, data, calendar

Qual a melhor maneira de se incrementar uma data do tipo `DD/MM/YYYY`?

Comment: [Olhee isso, voltando do almoço posto aqui](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: Trabalhar com datas em Java sempre foi algo terrível, uma das soluções mais adotadas é a biblioteca JODA-TIME, segue um tutorial:
http://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-joda-time/26524 Mas antes você pode testar a sugestão do @ldeoliveira

Answer (score 3):

Eu sugiro utilizar a classe [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

```
Date dataTeste = new Date();

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.setTime(dataTeste ); 
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
dataTeste = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: Detalhe: se quer usar a data atual, não precisa do `setTime`, pois `Calendar.getInstance()` já obtém a data atual :-)

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta diz "incrementar uma data do tipo **`DD/MM/YYYY`**", mas nenhuma das respostas se atentou para este formato específico.

De qualquer forma, esta é uma ótima oportunidade de esclarecer que, conforme já dito [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/364683/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/368075/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/367704/112052):

## Datas não têm formato

Uma data é apenas um conceito, uma ideia: ela representa um ponto específico no calendário.

A data de "26 de março de 2019", por exemplo, representa isso: o ponto específico do calendário que corresponde ao dia 26 do mês de março do ano de 2019.
Para expressar essa ideia em forma de texto, eu posso escrevê-la de diferentes formas:

- 26/03/2019 (um formato bem comum em muitos países, incluindo o Brasil)
- 3/26/2019 (formato americano, invertendo o dia e mês)
- 2019-03-26 (o formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601))
- 26 de Março de 2019 (em bom português)
- March 26<sup>th</sup>, 2019 (em inglês)
- 2019年3月26日 (em japonês)
- e muitos outros...

Repare que cada um dos formatos acima é diferente, mas **todos representam a mesma data** (os mesmos valores numéricos do dia, mês e ano).

Dito isso, uma "**data do tipo `DD/MM/YYYY`**" não faz sentido. Uma data é um ponto específico do calendário, e `DD/MM/YYYY` é apenas uma das muitas formas de representá-la. Provavelmente você quer dizer que tem uma `String` neste formato? E que só vai trabalhar com o dia, mês e ano?

---

Assumindo as duas premissas acima (`DD/MM/YYYY` é o formato da `String` e você só precisa trabalhar com o dia, mês e ano), existem algumas soluções, que dependem da versão do Java que você está usando.

### Java >= 8

A partir do Java 8 você pode usar um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) para criar um [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html):

```
String s = "26/03/2019";
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
LocalDate data = LocalDate.parse(s, parser);
```

Só que o `DateTimeFormatter`, por padrão, aceita alguns valores inválidos, como 31 de abril (e ajusta automaticamente para 30 de abril). Se quiser ser mais restrito e só aceitar datas válidas, use um [`java.time.format.ResolverStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html):

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu")
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
```

Para mais detalhes sobre o `ResolverStyle`, veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/370367/112052).

O `LocalDate` é uma classe que só possui o dia, mês e ano, por isso ela parece ser a melhor escolha para este caso. A API possui outras classes, caso você também precise das horas e do fuso horário, por exemplo (veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177130/112052) para mais detalhes).

Para somar um dia ao `LocalDate`, basta usar o método [`plusDays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusDays-long-):

```
LocalDate diaSeguinte = data.plusDays(1);
```

Lembrando que as classes do pacote `java.time` são imutáveis, e os métodos `plusXXX` sempre retornam **outra** instância. No exemplo acima, a variável `data` permanece inalterada (ela continua correspondendo a 26 de março de 2019), e a variável `diaSeguinte` corresponde a 27 de março de 2019. Claro que, se quiser, você pode atribuir o resultado na mesma variável:

```
data = data.plusDays(1);
```

Agora `data` equivale a 27 de março de 2019.

---

### Java 6 e 7

Para o Java 6 e 7 existe o [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), que é um excelente *backport* do `java.time`. As classes e métodos são basicamente os mesmos do `java.time`, a diferença é que elas ficam no pacote `org.threeten.bp` (ou seja, com exceção do nome do pacote, o código é igual ao exemplo acima).

Mas claro que você também pode usar a API nativa ([`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) e [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)):

```
// parsing da data no formato dd/MM/yyyy
String s = "26/03/2019";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse(s);

// somar 1 dia
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
date = cal.getTime(); // date agora corresponde a 27/03/2019
```

---

### Java 5

Para o Java 5, além da API nativa, uma boa alternativa é o [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/), que possui uma API parecida com o `java.time`:

```
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

String s = "26/03/2019";
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
LocalDate date = parser.parseLocalDate(s);
date = date.plusDays(1);
```

Vale lembrar que o Joda-Time é um projeto encerrado e em seu próprio site há um [aviso recomendando o uso do `java.time`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/#Support). Mas para quem ainda está preso ao Java 5, é uma alternativa melhor do que `Date` e `Calendar`.

---

Claro que você também pode trabalhar com a API legada ([`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html),  [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) e [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)). Mas isso esconde algumas "armadilhas". Por exemplo:

```
// supondo que o timezone default seja America/Sao_Paulo (Horário de Brasília)
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));

String s = "03/11/2018"; // 3 de novembro de 2018
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(sdf.parse(s));
System.out.println(cal.getTime()); // Sat Nov 03 00:00:00 BRT 2018

cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
System.out.println(cal.getTime()); // Sun Nov 04 01:00:00 BRST 2018
```

Eu chamei `TimeZone.setDefault` somente para simular que o timezone *default* da JVM é `America/Sao_Paulo` (mas vamos supor que sua JVM já está configurada assim). O que acontece neste caso, é que no dia 04/11/2018, à meia-noite, [teve início o horário de verão](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil/brasilia?year=2018), e os relógios foram adiantados em uma hora. Na prática, todos os minutos entre 00:00 e 00:59 são pulados, e o relógio pula diretamente de 23:49 para 01:00. Por isso, ao somar 1 dia na data "03/11/2018 00:00", o resultado é "04/11/2018 01:00".

O problema de `Date` e `Calendar` é que sempre haverá um timezone "agindo por baixo dos panos" (mesmo que em muitos casos você não perceba) e [não há muito como fugir disso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/295593/112052).

Já usando `LocalDate`, como visto acima, isso não acontece, já que um `LocalDate` só tem as informações do dia, mês e ano: não há nenhuma informação do horário, nem do timezone, e por isso esta classe não é afetada pelas configurações de timezone.

---

Claro que se o horário e o timezone forem importantes, você pode usar [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), que permite um controle maior sobre a data. O detalhe é que, diferente de `SimpleDateFormat`, que no exemplo acima vimos que preencheu o horário como meia-noite (pois a string não tinha horário e ele usa valores *default* para preencher o que falta), no `java.time` precisamos ser explícitos quanto ao que usar quando um valor não está presente:

```
String s = "03/11/2018"; // 3 de novembro de 2018
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
ZonedDateTime date = LocalDate.parse(s, parser) // faz o parsing da string
    // adiciona horário (meia-noite)
    .atTime(LocalTime.of(0, 0))
    // escolhe um timezone
    .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
date = date.plusDays(1);
System.out.println(date); // 2018-11-04T01:00-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
```

Claro que ainda permanece o "problema" do resultado ser dia 4 às 01:00, mas isso é por causa do horário de verão e não tem como fugir disso. Mas a vantagem é que temos mais controle aqui: eu posso escolher o horário (enquanto `SimpleDateFormat` sempre seta para meia-noite) e o timezone (embora com `SimpleDateFormat` também dê, usando o método `setTimeZone`).

Answer (score 0):

Algo assim deve funcionar(não sou expert em java):

```
String dt = "2008-01-01";  // A sua data
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  // número de dias a adicionar
dt = sdf.format(c.getTime());  // dt é a sua nova data com mais um dia
```

Answer (score 0):

Com java 8 dá pra fazer assim:

```
LocalDate hoje = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate amanha = hoje.plusDays(1);
```