# Erro na formatação de data quando é no dia do horário de verão brasileiro (BRST)

Tags: java, datetime, data

Estou com um problema na hora de retirar da uma variável date `(Sun Oct 21 01:00:00 BRST 2018)` essa uma hora de diferença, porque está gerando um erro de faturamento, quando a data é pegada do banco de dados com essa 1 hora de diferença.

Já tentei usar a conversão utilizando `Calendar`.

```
public static Date zeroTimes( final Date data ) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime( data );
    cal.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0 );
    cal.set( Calendar.MINUTE, 0 );
    cal.set( Calendar.SECOND, 0 );
    cal.set( Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0 );
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

Só que nunca consigo o retorno esperado que seria `Sun Oct 21 00:00:00 BRST 2018`.

Comment: Que tal mexer com [classes mais novas e otimizadas para isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/28595) ao inves de usar Calendar e Date?

Comment: Da pra fazer isso bem mais facil com as classes novas, há restricao de java-8 ou somente date e calendar mesmo?

Comment: Eu sei disso, só que as bibliotecas utilizadas na empresa não podem ser alteradas, e também não posso usar Joda time

Comment: Rodei seu código e o retorno foi o esperado por você: `Thu May 03 00:00:00 BRT 2018`

Answer (score 1):

Sua JVM ainda deve estar com as regras antigas do horário de verão. Até 2017, o horário de verão brasileiro começava no terceiro domingo de outubro, porém em dezembro de 2017 [o governo mudou a regra](https://g1.globo.com/economia/noticia/horario-de-verao-comecara-em-novembro-e-nao-mais-em-outubro-a-partir-de-2018-informa-planalto.ghtml) e a partir de 2018, o início será no primeiro domingo de novembro.

Como essas configurações ficam na JVM, ela ainda pensa que o horário de verão vai começar em 21 de outubro de 2018. Prova disso é o **"BRST"**, que é a abreviação de ["Brasília Summer Time"](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/brst) (outro nome para o horário de verão do Brasil).

Para corrigir, você deve atualizar as informações de fuso horário da JVM. Há 2 formas de fazê-lo:

1. Atualizar a versão do Java. [Nesta página](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html) você pode ver que as versões 10, 8u172, 7u181 e 6u191 possuem o **tzdata2018c**, que é a versão que possui as novas regras do horário de verão brasileiro (veja na quarta coluna: *"Brazil's DST will now start on November's first Sunday"*). Basta atualizar o Java para uma destas versões.
2. Atualizar somente o *tzdata* da JVM (as informações de fuso horário), sem mudar a versão do Java. Para isso, você precisa rodar o [TZ Updater Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html). Um dos argumentos deste comando é o arquivo que você vai usar, e o mesmo pode ser encontrado em https://www.iana.org/time-zones

   O arquivo mais recente sempre pode ser baixado em https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tzdata-latest.tar.gz. Você pode baixá-lo e rodar o comando [conforme as instruções](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html#usage). Mas sempre verifique o [site da IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) para saber se há um arquivo mais recente. [Nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/338320/112052) há uma explicação mais detalhada sobre como fazer esta atualização, e [neste link](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/) estão todas as versões, caso precise de alguma anterior à atual.

A minha JVM já foi atualizada, por isso a saída do seu código para mim é:

> Sun Oct 21 00:00:00 BRT 2018

Note que não é mais "BRST", e sim "BRT", indicando que não está em horário de verão.

---

Sem atualizar as informações de fuso horário, não é possível setar o horário para meia-noite no dia 21, por causa da forma como funciona o horário de verão.

Quando o horário de verão começa, acontece o seguinte: no momento em que chega meia-noite, o relógio é automaticamente adiantado em uma hora.  Literalmente "pulamos" uma hora: todos os minutos entre 00:00 e 00:59 **não existem** neste dia.

Atualmente os computadores e celulares já possuem estas configurações e mudam automaticamente. O relógio pula de 23:59:59 direto para 01:00. Por isso, quando começa o horário de verão, não existe meia-noite nesse dia, e a API ajusta para o próximo horário válido (no caso, 01:00).

E como a sua JVM ainda está com as regras antigas, ela acha que o horário de verão começa dia 21 de outubro, e por isso não é possível setar a hora para meia-noite neste dia.

---

Detalhe: após atualizar a JVM, o problema do dia 21 será corrigido. Porém, esta situação ainda ocorrerá no dia 4 de novembro, quando começar o horário de verão. Não adianta, sempre haverá algum dia em que o relógio é adiantado e determinados horários não existem naquele timezone.