# Java mostra data no horário de verão, mesmo com sistema operacional atualizado

Tags: java, timezone

Efetuamos a alteração de entrada do horário de verão 2018 no Sistema Operacional (Linux ou Windows), mas a aplicação JAVA mostra a hora errada (com horário de verão).

Comment: O Java mantém estas informações dentro da própria JVM, separadas do sistema operacional. Para atualizar, vc pode usar o TZUpdater Tool: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/tzupdater-readme-136440.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Descobrimos que o JAVA possui um DST (Daylight Saving Time) próprio e que é necessário atualizar a configuração devido a alteração padrão.

## JAVA ORACLE ou OPENJDK

1. Efetuar o download da [última versão do TZDATA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones)
2. Efetuar o download do [TZUpdater Tool](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/tzupdater-download-513681.html)
3. Executar o comando abaixo (especificar o caminho completo)

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=caminho do java
   java -jar tzupdater.jar -f -l file:///home/USER/Downloads/tzdata-latest.tar.gz
   ```

**Se ocorrer o erro, basta descompactar o arquivo tzdata, comentar a linha do arquivo e retornar a compactar o TZDATA**.

```
Using file:///home/USER/Downloads/tzdata-latest.tar.gz as source for tzdata bundle.
Failed: java.lang.Exception: Failed while parsing file '/tmp/tz.tmp_6/asia' on line 1655 'Rule  Japan   1948    1951    -   Sep Sat>=8  25:00   0   S'
java.lang.Exception: Failed while parsing file '/tmp/tz.tmp_6/asia' on line 1655 'Rule  Japan   1948    1951    -   Sep Sat>=8  25:00   0   S'
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.parseFile(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:377)
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.compile(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:191)
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.<init>(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:307)
    at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.ExternalModule.compileToJSRBinary(ExternalModule.java:153)
    at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.run(TimezoneUpdater.java:230)
    at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.main(TimezoneUpdater.java:634)
Caused by: tools.tzdb.DateTimeException: Invalid value for SecondOfDay value: 90000
    at tools.tzdb.ChronoField.checkValidValue(ChronoField.java:173)
    at tools.tzdb.LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(LocalTime.java:210)
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.parseMonthDayTime(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:475)
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.parseRuleLine(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:399)
    at tools.tzdb.TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.parseFile(TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java:354)
    ... 5 more
```

4. Saída padrão

   ```
   java -jar tzupdater.jar -f -l file:///home/USER/Downloads/tzupdater-2.2.0/tzdata/tzdata.tar.gz 

   Using file:///home/USER/Downloads/tzupdater-2.2.0/tzdata/tzdata.tar.gz as source for tzdata bundle.
   ```

## JAVA IBM

1. Efetuar [download da ferramenta IBM Time Zone Update Utility](https://developer.ibm.com/javasdk/support/dst/jtzu/)
2. Criar diretório `/tmp/jtzu`, copiar arquivo para a pasta e descomprimir arquivo

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/jtzu
   cd /tmp/jtzu
   scp jtzu-1.7.18e.zip /tmp/jtzu
   unzip jtzu-1.7.18e.zip
   ```
3. Altere o arquivo `runjtzuenv.sh`, setando `NOGUI` para desabilitar a interface gráfica

   ```
   NOGUI=true
   ```
4. Execute o arquivo para efetuar discovery das JVMs

   ```
   bash runjtzu.sh
   ```
5. O comando anterior gera o arquivo `SDKList.txt` com todas as instalações de Java encontradas.
6. Altere o arquivo `runjtzuenv.sh`

   ```
   NOGUI=true
   DISCOVERONLY=false
   SILENTPATCH=false
   ```
7. Execute o arquivo novamente

   ```
   bash runjtzu.sh
   ```

Comment: Criei um repositório com a correção citada acima já compactada:

https://github.com/psybox/tzdata_temer